# perforce overriding history of a version?

Tags: perforce

We are using versions and have those versions pre-burned-in into images, however if there was a mistake we would like to push a file in but not version-up? Basically overwriting the Revision of that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your "versions" that you're referencing in your images to be mutable, you probably don't want them to be actual Perforce revision numbers.  Revisions and changelists in Perforce are generally considered to be immutable.  A better fit for what you're trying to do might be a **label**, which is a version specifier with an arbitrary name that can be arbitrarily reassigned to point to different revisions.

That said: if you want to replace an existing revision in Perforce, it's possible to do it with admin commands -- you can obliterate the latest revision and submit a new one (which will reuse the same number),  or you can "unsubmit" it (which essentially obliterates the revision and then puts it in a shelved changelist instead of completely discarding it).  This approach is *very* heavyweight though and if you try to turn it into a regular workflow you will probably end up discovering a bunch of new problems that have to be solved (how do we deal with the permissions, how do we handle race conditions, what about inconsistencies with other workspaces...).  I'd recommend looking into the label approach first.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I think I should look into labels.

Comment: Coming back to this thread, `obliterate the lastest revision` is an option that I've tried, however, this is a little scary. How does the exact workflow for `unsubmit` look like? Our current system works now (submitted more than 5000 changes to a folder) but we had a case where one version needed to be manually fixed.

Comment: `p4 help unsubmit`.  As I said in my original answer, this is fine for a one-off, but if you try to turn it into a regular workflow (which it sounds like is more the case), you will probably be unhappy.  Don't say nobody warned you!  :)